# How do I get mouseover called on all elements under the cursor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a web application where every time you click, a dot is created (see below). When I mouse over a stack of dots, I expected to have every dot under the cursor have its mouseover or mouseenter event fire. However, only one event is fired, that for the dot "on top" of the stack.

How would you get the mouseover or mouseenter event to fire for every dot under the cursor (but not those that aren't under the cursor) when the mouse is moved over a stack of multiple dots? (BEGIN EDIT) Additionally, the mouseout or mouseleave event should only fire when the cursor actually leaves the dot. (END EDIT)

In case it's important, the whole black portion in the picture is a SVG, and the dots are all SVG circles. Each dot is a sibling with all the other dots, and all are children of the SVG element.

[image: web app with dots showing]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have the first dot, set its CSS "pointer-events" property to "none" and then call [document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) using the co-ordinates you have. Repeat till you run out of dots.

You may need to suppress the mouse handler while you're doing this so you don't get unwanted mouseout/mouseenter events as the elements under the mouse pointer change.

Comment: Just for those looking at this in the future, you get the coordinates of the mouse using event.pageX and event.pageY. I ended up using the process in this answer on mouseclick on the whole SVG instead of mouseover of a dot.

Comment: This answer is a good suggestion, but I find it impossible to do the task with `document.elementFromPoint()`, since only the topmost element is returned. However, one can use the `document.elementsFromPoint()` method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint), which returns "an array of all elements at the specified coordinates".

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, the event is being dispatched only to the event handler registered for the topmost "dot" in the stack.  Expand this event handler to programmatically search all other dots and determine whether they may overlap the current position of the sprite.  If so, mechanically invoke their event handlers individually--specifying a flag so that the "programmatic search [of] all other dots" doesn't happen FOR THEM also, which will never end.  If you're unable to add a flag to the event handler, add some field to some object that the event handler can observe (e.g., the data structure that corresponds to a dot), and set or clear that flag (a good name might be "isCheckForOverlappingDots") beforehand.

Comment: I think this answer would work for simple cases, but it looks like it might be a little CPU heavy for mine (there could be tens of thousands of dots on the map in normal use, the computer will place as many as you want after you place the first few to show it roughly where things should go). Thanks for the answer, though!