# Detecting Multiple Overlapping SVG Shape Elements on Mouse Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, mouseevent

I'm trying to detect the overlapping of different SVG Elements on mouseup events like shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yesin/w0wufbtn/70/) using only rectangle shapes.

```
$('svg').on('mouseup', function(evt) {
  var root = $('svg')[0];
  var rpos = root.createSVGRect();
  rpos.x = evt.clientX;
  rpos.y = evt.clientY;
  rpos.width = rpos.height = 1;
  var list = root.getIntersectionList(rpos, null);

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i] != evt.target) {
      $(list[i]).mouseup();
    }
  }
});
```

I want to be able to detect the overlapping on mouseup between rectangle, circle as well as polygon shapes like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yesin/86zxh3af/5/) I've been trying with but using getIntersectionList() only seems to work for rectangle shapes only.

One other way seems to be getting the root SVG coordinates on mouseup and  checking if it matched any of the coordinates inside of the SVG elements.

Is there a better way for me to detect the intersections of multiple SVG element shapes on mouseup?

Comment: When you say intersections, do you really mean which elements are under the cursor ?

Comment: @Ian, Yes. To get the list of elements under the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Firefox does not support `getIntersectionList()`. I am not sure about Chrome or other browsers.

A workaround approach is described in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38724176/how-do-i-get-mouseover-called-on-all-elements-under-the-cursor).